# Problem with screencapture of flash animation in chromium-browser

Tags: chrome, vnc, adobe-flash

I'm using chromium-browser and a vnc4 server to do some thumbnailing of flash resources.  This is the version:

```
$ chromium-browser --version
Using PPAPI flash.
Chromium 48.0.2564.116 Ubuntu 14.04
```

This is what I do when I try to do the capture:

```
sudo vnc4server  -kill :1
vnc4server 
export DISPLAY=:1
sudo xhost +local: 
chromium-browser "<url to load the resource on our website>"
```

This has worked in the past; I would proceed to do a couple of interactions (pressing play buttons etc), then do a screengrab.  But now it's hanging, displaying this output:

```
Using PPAPI flash.
Xlib:  extension "XInputExtension" missing on display ":1".
Xlib:  extension "XInputExtension" missing on display ":1".
Xlib:  extension "XInputExtension" missing on display ":1".
[3121:3121:0322/164259:ERROR:logging.h(808)] Failed to call method: org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager.GetManagedObjects: object_path= /: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.bluez was not provided by any .service files
[3121:3121:0322/164259:ERROR:logging.h(808)] Failed to call method: org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager.GetManagedObjects: object_path= /: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.bluez was not provided by any .service files
Xlib:  extension "XInputExtension" missing on display ":1".
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
[3176:3176:0322/164300:ERROR:gl_surface_glx.cc(347)] GLX 1.3 or later is required.
[3176:3176:0322/164300:ERROR:gl_surface_x11.cc(56)] GLSurfaceGLX::InitializeOneOff failed.
[3176:3176:0322/164300:ERROR:gpu_child_thread.cc(257)] Exiting GPU process due to errors during initialization
[3121:3155:0322/164300:ERROR:browser_gpu_channel_host_factory.cc(132)] Failed to launch GPU process.
[WARNING:flash/platform/pepper/pep_module.cpp(63)] SANDBOXED
Vector smash protection is enabled.
```

Now, apart from hanging the terminal, this does seem to be working.  I can open another terminal and do the interactions and screengrabs in there just fine, like so:

```
#click play button
sudo xdotool mousemove 160 655; sudo xdotool click 1
#screengrab
sudo import -display :1 -window root -crop 800x600+11+83 /path/to/output.jpg
```

So, maybe I can actually ignore this problem if I find a way to bypass the hanging command.  I tried adding an `&` on the end, like so:

```
chromium-browser "<url to load the resource on our website>" &
```

But it's still hanging.  It's also hanging if I do

```
chromium-browser "<url to load the resource on our website>" >/dev/null
```

I've also tried starting it with `nohup` in front of the command (still hangs, but with no output) and `nohup` at the start with `&` at the end (same).

I'm out of ideas. I'm not familiar enough with vnc4 or chromium-browser to know what this error even means, let alone try to fix it.  Can anyone advise?

Comment: Reading your log, you have a swrast trouble and a GLX 1.3 trouble. You should fix it first.

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling chromium. Maybe a glitch happened. If this doesn't work maybe you have to delete some of its library files and try reinstalling again.

I hope this fixes your problem!

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with the chromium browser when taking screenshots. See [this bug report](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=510291).